# TS test! How to write this JS code in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a very complicated SDK, and now I want to make it a layer of code encapsulation. I tried to use the union type and the index type to solve it. I wrote a demo as shown below. How do I use typescript to implement the bar method and pass the console test?

JS code:

```js
class Foo {
  add (a, b) {
    return a + b
  }
  isZero (num) {
    return num === 0
  }
  free (...args) {
    return args.join('-')
  }
}

const foo = new Foo()

function bar(funcName) {
  return (...args) => {
    return foo[funcName](...args)
  }
}

console.log( bar('add')('1', '2') ) // 12
console.log( bar('isZero')(10) ) // false
console.log( bar('free')('a', 1, '2', 'c', 'd') ) // a-1-2-c-d
```

TS code:

```js
class Foo {
  add (a: string, b: string): string {
    return a + b
  }
  isZero (num: number): boolean {
    return num === 0
  }
  free (...params: any[]): string {
    return params.join('-')
  }
}

const foo = new Foo()

function bar(funcName: keyof Foo) {
  // How to write the code here?
}

console.log( bar('add')('1', '2') )
console.log( bar('isZero')(10) )
console.log( bar('free')('a', 1, '2', 'c', 'd') )
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current `bar` may be simplified a little.

```
function bar<T extends keyof Foo>(funcName: T): Foo[T] {
  return foo[funcName];
}
```

Is it OK, or in real example you need to do something with arguments besides passing it to the implementing class method?